# How to organize a XML variable content into a table (untyped data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, reporting-services

I have a database in SQL Server and one of its columns its a XML whose content (root, child and subchilds) may vary according to a given parameter of which there are more than 30 different types.

**[Image of the database filtered by a provided number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl5Xy.png)**

As long as **I don't have access to the documentation and I don't know their structure (untyped data),** I need to find a mecanism that allows me to **transform the content of this XML column into variables of a new db**.

What I mean: The query would identify the content of my XML (which number of nodes can vary as well), organize the root, child and subchilds, put it into a table. Could you kindly take a look at the code and give some advice about how could I transform a line by line (this is what the code does) into a table? Thank you!

```
DECLARE @xmlText VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT TOP 1 @xmlText = CAST(ContenuTransmission AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM pgisCBL.dbo.Transmission WHERE NoReferenceTransmission = '1411130048'
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xmlTest') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #xmlTest -- SELECT * FROM #xmlTest WHERE TagType = 3
SELECT
    ID
    ,Valeur + '>' as Tag
    ,CASE WHEN LEFT(Valeur + '>',2) = '</' AND RIGHT(Valeur + '>',1) = '>'                                       THEN 3 -- EndSection
          WHEN LEFT(Valeur + '>',1) = '<'  AND RIGHT(Valeur + '>',1) = '>' AND CHARINDEX('=', Valeur + '>') > 0  THEN 1 -- Section with values
          WHEN LEFT(Valeur + '>',1) = '<'  AND RIGHT(Valeur + '>',1) = '>' AND CHARINDEX('=', Valeur + '>') = 0  THEN 1 -- Section start
          ELSE 2 -- Value for previous section start
     END AS TagType
INTO #xmlTest
FROM IG.dbo.ftSplitDelimiteMax(@xmlText,'>')
WHERE Valeur + '>' <> '>'

SELECT * FROM #xmlTest

-- IDENTIFY INDENTS AND OUTDENTS AND PUT THE ELEMENTS SIDE BY SIDE
; WITH
    cteOutdent AS (SELECT
                        ID
                        ,REPLACE(REPLACE(Tag,'/',''),'>','') AS Tag
                        ,LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(Tag,'/',''),'>','')) AS LenTag
                        ,-2 AS Indent
                    FROM #xmlTest
                    WHERE TagType = 3)
,   cteIndent AS (SELECT
                        #xmlTest.ID + 1 AS ID
                        ,#xmlTest.Tag 
                        ,2 AS Indent
                    FROM #xmlTest
                    INNER JOIN cteOutdent 
                    ON cteOutdent.Tag = LEFT(#xmlTest.Tag,cteOutdent.LenTag)
                    WHERE TagType <> 3)
,   cteIndents AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                        ID,
                        Indent
                    FROM cteIndent 
                    UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        ID,
                        Indent
                    FROM cteOutdent)
SELECT
    a.ID
    ,CASE WHEN b.TagType = 2 THEN a.Tag + b.Tag ELSE a.tag END AS xmlLine
    ,ISNULL(cteIndents.Indent,0) AS Indent
FROM
    #xmlTest a
    LEFT JOIN #xmlTest b
    ON b.id = a.ID + 1
    LEFT JOIN cteIndents ON cteIndents.Id = a.ID
WHERE a.TagType in (1,3)
ORDER BY a.ID
```

**[Results of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0z6R.png)**

Comment: so, you expect us to know their structure and give you code to convert xml to db table rows, right? why do you think that it is possible?

Comment: Actually not. I am looking for a general solution that would be capable to identify a xml structure and organize it without declaring the names of the variables I am looking for (what I don't know).

Comment: then you have to wait a little bit, AI is not invented yet

Comment: If you would like help with a solution you are attempting or would like feedback on it, that is one thing. But did you just post what you want to do and asked SO to do it for you?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I could have been more specific and should have asked for feedback on an exemple. This is what I am trying to do and it puts my nodes line by line. I will post in 2 parts:

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43803781/5089204). You'll find some approaches to analyse and shredd any XML into table data (at least kind of *key-value-pair* or better: *XPath-key-value-pair*). You will not find any automatism to shredd any XML with any strcuture into neatly defined related tables...

Comment: Thank you Shnugo. I saw the solution and I think this is going to help me to solve a big part of the question. I'll try it on monday! :)

Comment: Shnugo, the John Capelletti's solution was exactly what I needed and didn't find. It totally applies to my case. Very dynamic function! Thank you for answering and sharing it.

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to read this... Just one hint: Without the `@` before `@Shnugo` there is no alert, I found your comment by chance...

Comment: Thank you @Shnugo for the alert. I am new in this forum. :)

Answer (score 0):

**The called John Capelletti's function, whose link was shared by @Shnugo:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ftCollapseXML](@XML xml)

Returns Table 
As Return

with  cte0 as ( 
                  Select Lvl       = 1
                        ,ID        = Cast(1 as int) 
                        ,Pt        = Cast(NULL as int)
                        ,Element   = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                        ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(150))
                        ,Value     = x.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')
                        ,XPath     = cast(concat(x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)'),'[' ,cast(Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(max))
                        ,Seq       = cast(1000000+Row_Number() over(Order By (Select 1)) as varchar(max))
                        ,AttData   = x.query('.') 
                        ,XMLData   = x.query('*') 
                  From   @XML.nodes('/*') a(x) 
                  Union  All
                  Select Lvl       = p.Lvl + 1 
                        ,ID        = Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10
                        ,Pt        = p.ID
                        ,Element   = c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                        ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(150))
                        ,Value     = cast( c.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max) ) 
                        ,XPath     = cast(concat(p.XPath,'/',c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)'),'[',cast(Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)') Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(max) )
                        ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10) as varchar(max))
                        ,AttData   = c.query('.') 
                        ,XMLData   = c.query('*') 
                  From   cte0 p 
                  Cross  Apply p.XMLData.nodes('*') b(c) 
              )
    , cte1 as (   
                  Select R1 = Row_Number() over (Order By Seq),A.*
                  From  (
                          Select  Lvl,ID,Pt,Element,Attribute,Value,XPath,Seq From cte0
                          Union All
                          Select Lvl       = p.Lvl+1
                                ,ID        = p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                                ,Pt        = p.ID
                                ,Element   = p.Element
                                ,Attribute = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(150)')
                                ,Value     = x.value('.','varchar(max)')
                                ,XPath     = p.XPath + '/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')
                                ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) ) as varchar(max))
                          From   cte0 p 
                          Cross  Apply AttData.nodes('/*/@*') a(x) 
                        ) A 
               )

Select A.R1
      ,R2  = IsNull((Select max(R1) From cte1 Where Seq Like A.Seq+'%'),A.R1)
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Element
      ,A.Attribute
      ,A.XPath
      ,Title = Replicate('|---',Lvl-1)+Element+IIF(Attribute='','','@'+Attribute)
      ,A.Value
 From  cte1 A
GO
```