# Working with MultiLevel XML in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, xml, parsing

I have a client API which sends me an XML in the following format. I have to change few values and send the same XML to my client's another API. What is the best possible way to do it. We are currently using SQL Server 2014 and C#.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<JobPositionPostings>
    <JobPositionPosting>
        <JobAction>ADD</JobAction>
        <JobType>p</JobType>
        <JobPositionPostingID>27</JobPositionPostingID>
        <HiringOrg>
            <HiringOrgName>Company Name</HiringOrgName>
            <Industry>
                <SummaryText>Brief description of the hiring organization</SummaryText>
            </Industry>
            <Contact>
                <PersonName>
                    <FormattedName>Name of the Hiring Contact</FormattedName>
                </PersonName>
            </Contact>
        </HiringOrg>
        <JobDisplayOptions>
            <MicrositeName>Client Microsite Name</MicrositeName>
            <TemplateName>Client Template Name</TemplateName>
        </JobDisplayOptions>
        <JobPositionInformation>
            <JobPositionTitle>R and D manager #2 banglore</JobPositionTitle>
            <JobClassifications>
                <PrimaryJobCategory>
                    <JobIndustryCode>7</JobIndustryCode>
                    <JobFunctionCode>8</JobFunctionCode>
                    <JobRoleCode>8.31</JobRoleCode>
                </PrimaryJobCategory>
            </JobClassifications>
            <JobPositionDescription>
                <JobKeywords>Java</JobKeywords>
                <JobPositionLocation>
                    <InterNationalLoc></InterNationalLoc>
                    <InterNationalLocOther></InterNationalLocOther>
                    <IndianLoc>25.30.159</IndianLoc>
                    <IndianLocOther></IndianLocOther>
                </JobPositionLocation>
                <CompensationDescription>
                    <Pay>
                        <SalaryCurrency>Rupees</SalaryCurrency>
                        <MinimumSalary>250000</MinimumSalary>
                        <MaximumSalary>325000</MaximumSalary>
                        <DisplaySalary>Y</DisplaySalary>
                    </Pay>
                    <BenifitsDescription>Job Benefits Description</BenifitsDescription>
                </CompensationDescription>
                <SummaryText>Job Description(brief about JD)</SummaryText>
            </JobPositionDescription>
            <JobPositionRequirements>
                <SummaryText>Desired Candidate Profile Summary Text - Required Competencies/Skills/Leadership E-mail
         </SummaryText>
                <JobExperience>
                    <MinimumExperience>2</MinimumExperience>
                    <MaximumExperience>4</MaximumExperience>
                </JobExperience>
                <JobQualifications>
                    <UGQualifications />
                    <UGSpecializations />
                    <PGQualifications />
                    <PGSpecializations />
                </JobQualifications>
            </JobPositionRequirements>
            <AddJobsToRefSite>true</AddJobsToRefSite>
            <ReferenceCode>Your Unique Job Reference code</ReferenceCode>
        </JobPositionInformation>
        <HowToApply>
            <ApplicationMethods>
                <ByEmail>
                    <E-mail>Client E-mail for Response Management , in case not using ATS Integration
           </E-mail>
                </ByEmail>
                <ByWeb>
                    <URL></URL>
                    <ApplyIntegration>1</ApplyIntegration>
                </ByWeb>
                <QUESTIONNAIRE>Standard Questionnaire name if you know the same, else contact your Account manager</QUESTIONNAIRE>
            </ApplicationMethods>
        </HowToApply>
        <ReferralDetails>
            <Amount> 1000</Amount>
            <Benefit>  gift voucher</Benefit>
        </ReferralDetails>
    </JobPositionPosting>
    <JobFeedResponseEmail>Tech person's E-mail for receiving Feed Status</JobFeedResponseEmail>
</JobPositionPostings>
```

I am following the below approach. I replaced all the value fields in my XML with some variables by separating them with pipe(|) symbols. Please find below the replaced one.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<JobPositionPostings>
   <JobPositionPosting>
                    <JobAction>|JAct_M|</JobAction>
                    <JobPositionPostingID>|JID_M|</JobPositionPostingID>
                    <JobType>|JType_M|</JobType>
   <HiringOrg>
                    <WebSite>|JWebSite_N|</WebSite>
                    <HiringOrgName>|JComp_M|</HiringOrgName>
        <Industry>
                    <SummaryText>|JCompDesc_M|</SummaryText>
        </Industry>
    <Contact>
            <PersonName>
                    <FormattedName>|JContactName_N|</FormattedName>
            </PersonName>
    </Contact>
   </HiringOrg>
   <JobDisplayOptions>
                    <MicrositeName>|JMSite_S|</MicrositeName>
                    <TemplateName>|JTempl_N|</TemplateName>
   </JobDisplayOptions>
   <JobPositionInformation>
                    <JobPositionTitle>|JTitle_M|</JobPositionTitle>
       <JobClassifications>
            <PrimaryJobCategory>
                    <JobIndustryCode>|JIndustryCode_M|</JobIndustryCode>
                    <JobFunctionCode>|JFunCode_M|</JobFunctionCode>
                    <JobRoleCode>|JRoleCode_M|</JobRoleCode>
            </PrimaryJobCategory>
       </JobClassifications>
       <JobPositionDescription>
                    <JobKeywords>|JSkills_M|</JobKeywords>
            <JobPositionLocation>
                    <InterNationalLoc>|JIntlCode_M|</InterNationalLoc>
                    <InterNationalLocOther>|JIntlCodeOther_N|</InterNationalLocOther>
                    <IndianLoc>|JLocCode_M|</IndianLoc>
                    <IndianLocOther>|JLocOther_N|</IndianLocOther>
            </JobPositionLocation>
            <CompensationDescription>
                <Pay>
                        <SalaryCurrency>|JCurr_M|</SalaryCurrency>
                        <MinimumSalary>|JMinSal_M|</MinimumSalary>
                        <MaximumSalary>|JMaxSal_M|</MaximumSalary>
                        <DisplaySalary>|JSalDisp_N|</DisplaySalary>
                </Pay>
                    <BenifitsDescription>|JBenefits_N|</BenifitsDescription>
            </CompensationDescription>
                    <SummaryText>|JJD_M|</SummaryText>
       </JobPositionDescription>
       <JobPositionRequirements>
                    <SummaryText>|JDesCand_N|</SummaryText>
            <JobExperience>
                    <MinimumExperience>|JMinExp_M|</MinimumExperience>
                    <MaximumExperience>|JMaxExp_M|</MaximumExperience>
            </JobExperience>
            <JobQualifications>
                    <UGQualifications>|JQual1_M|</UGQualifications>
                    <UGSpecializations>|JSpec1_M|</UGSpecializations>
                    <PGQualifications>|JQual2_M|</PGQualifications>
                    <PGSpecializations>|JSpec2_M|</PGSpecializations>
                    <DoctorateQualifications>|JQual3_M|</DoctorateQualifications>
                    <DoctorateSpecializations>|JSpec3_M|</DoctorateSpecializations>
            </JobQualifications>
       </JobPositionRequirements>
                <AddJobsToRefSite>|JRefSite_N|</AddJobsToRefSite>
                <ReferenceCode>|JRefCode_N|</ReferenceCode>
    </JobPositionInformation>
    <HowToApply>
            <ApplicationMethods>
                <ByEmail>
                    <E-mail>|JLntMail_M|</E-mail>
                </ByEmail>
            <ByEapps> 
                <Eapps>|JeApps_M|</Eapps> 
            </ByEapps>
                <ByWeb>
                    <URL>|JURL_M|</URL>
                    <ApplyIntegration>|JAppInt_M|</ApplyIntegration> 
                </ByWeb>
                <QUESTIONNAIRE>|JQuest_N|</QUESTIONNAIRE>
            </ApplicationMethods>
     </HowToApply>
     <ReferralDetails>
                        <Benefit>|JBenefit_N|</Benefit>
                        <Amount>|JBAmt_N|</Amount>
     </ReferralDetails>
  </JobPositionPosting>
                <JobFeedResponseEmail>|JFeedRespEmail_N|</JobFeedResponseEmail>
</JobPositionPostings>
```

After that in SQL server I am replacing them with desired values and forwarding that XML to my client.

```
set @Nxml = replace(@Nxml, '|JAct_M|','Add')
set @Nxml = replace(@Nxml, '|JID_M|',@reqmt_id)
set @Nxml = replace(@Nxml, '|JType_M|','P')
```

Is this best method or is there any other easy approach.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're using API why do you replace values with pipe-surrounded identifiers? Why not using XPath and do this in C# code? Or is it requirement to replace values in SQL?

Comment: I have no knowledge of xml, i am new to xml, so just wanted to know if the one which iam using is the best method or is there any other easy best method. Now my main problem is how to read values from the received xml file, replace few values and then again convert it to same xml in same format and send it.

Comment: As you are rather new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: Is this question solved? If yes, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you are modifying a lot of elements.  So I recommend using serialization.  Below is a start.  I read file and deserialized, then wrote same results.  I recommend you continue like I've done with original data and compare input and output to be the same.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JobPositionPostings postings = Load(INPUT_FILENAME);

            // modify posting here

            Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME, postings);

        }
        static JobPositionPostings Load(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(JobPositionPostings));
            JobPositionPostings postings =  (JobPositionPostings)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            return postings;
        }
        static void Save(string filename, JobPositionPostings postings)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(JobPositionPostings));
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);

            serializer.Serialize(writer, postings);

        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("JobPositionPostings")]
    public class JobPositionPostings
    {
        [XmlElement("JobPositionPosting")]
        public List<JobPositionPosting> jobPositionPostings { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("JobPositionPosting")]
    public class JobPositionPosting
    {
        [XmlElement("JobAction")]
        public string JobAction { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("JobType")]
        public string jobType { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("JobPositionPostingID")]
        public int jobPositionPostingID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("HiringOrg")]
        public HiringOrg hiringOrg { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("JobDisplayOptions")]
        public JobDisplayOptions jobDisplayOptions { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("HiringOrg")]
    public class HiringOrg
    {

        [XmlElement("HiringOrgName")]
        public string hiringOrgName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Industry")]
        public Industry industry { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Contact")]
        public Contact contact { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot("Industry")]
    public class Industry
    {
        [XmlElement("SummaryText")]
        public string summaryText { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Contact")]
        public string contact { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Contact")]
    public class Contact
    {
       [XmlElement("PersonName")]
        public PersonName personName { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("PersonName")]
    public class PersonName
    {
        [XmlElement("FormattedName")]
        public string formattedName { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("JobDisplayOptions")]
    public class JobDisplayOptions
    {
        [XmlElement("MicrositeName")]
        public string micrositeName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TemplateName")]
        public string templateName { get; set; }
}




}
```

Comment: AFAIU, Prasanth Kumar doesn't own the API - and thus it can be changed any time (and it looks like an overkill to me...)

Comment: This is the standard method that is used millions of times.  It is not an overkill and is the method that normally used when reading/writing/changing lots of xml tags.

Comment: How do i change value for a node in the above example.

Comment: postings.jobPositionPostings[0].jobDisplayOptions.micrositeName = "abc";

Comment: I am sorry, i mean suppose i have more than one element node, for example "FormattedName" can be more than one, in such a case my output xml should have more "FormattedName" elements as follows, <FormattedName>Pkv</FormattedName> <FormattedName>DSP</FormattedName> how do i achieve this

Comment: You would need to change the class property to a list object (still use XmlElement).  Just like jobPostiionPostings in the first class.

Comment: yaa, that worked thank you, i did the following changes  [XmlElement(ElementName = "FormattedName")]
        public List<string> FormattedName{ get; set; }  postings.JobPositionPosting.HiringOrg.Contact.PersonName.FormattedName..Add("Pkv");

Answer (score 0):

The best approach (only in the case that you should get xml, modify it and then pass by modified xml) would be to use XPathNavigator (example to change your JobAction):

```
public static string UpdateJobAction(string inputXml)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(inputXml);

        var xpnavigator = xmlDocument.CreateNavigator();
        foreach (XPathNavigator xpn in xpnavigator.Select("//JobPositionPostings/JobPositionPosting/JobAction"))
        {
            var value = xpn.Value; // to obtain the JobAction value
            xpn.SetValue("Add");
        }
        return xpnavigator.OuterXml;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, is there any query in sql through which i can convert the entire above xml into an sql server table, in the above xml, this particular tag <IndianLoc>25.30.159</IndianLoc> repeats for all the applicable locations.

Comment: @PrasanthKumar At [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43803781/5089204) you'll find such a magic function (and links to more approaches). But it won't help you probably. The result is kind of an enhanced *Key (`XPath`) - Value - Pair*. The problem would be to get your XML back...

Answer (score 0):

To modify XML with SQL-Server you can use the XML data type's function `.modify()`. First you must cast/convert your XML to the **real** XML type.

**Do not deal with XML on string level!**

Check this (shortened for brevity):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<JobPositionPostings>
    <JobPositionPosting>
        <JobAction>ADD</JobAction>
        <JobType>p</JobType>
        <JobPositionPostingID>27</JobPositionPostingID>
        <HiringOrg>
            <HiringOrgName>Company Name</HiringOrgName>
            <Industry>
                <SummaryText>Brief description of the hiring organization</SummaryText>
            </Industry>
            <Contact>
                <PersonName>
                    <FormattedName>Name of the Hiring Contact</FormattedName>
                </PersonName>
            </Contact>
        </HiringOrg>
        <JobDisplayOptions>
            <MicrositeName>Client Microsite Name</MicrositeName>
            <TemplateName>Client Template Name</TemplateName>
        </JobDisplayOptions>
        <!-- More nodes -->   
    </JobPositionPosting>
    <JobFeedResponseEmail>Tech person''s E-mail for receiving Feed Status</JobFeedResponseEmail>
</JobPositionPostings>';
```

--Replace one specific **existing** element's value with a *hardcoded* new value

```
SET @xml.modify(N'replace value of (/JobPositionPostings/JobPositionPosting/JobAction/text())[1] with "SomeNewValue"');
```

--You can use `sql:variable("@SomeVariable")` or `sql:column("SomeColumn")` to take a value dynamically

```
DECLARE @NewJobType NVARCHAR(100)='NewType';
SET @xml.modify(N'replace value of (/JobPositionPostings/JobPositionPosting/JobType/text())[1] with sql:variable("@NewJobType")');
```

--Introduce a new element at a specific position

```
SET @xml.modify(N'insert <SomeNewElement>test</SomeNewElement> after (/JobPositionPostings/JobPositionPosting/JobType)[1]');
```

--remove one (complete) element

```
SET @xml.modify(N'delete (/JobPositionPostings/JobPositionPosting/HiringOrg)[1]');
```

--Check the modified result

```
SELECT @xml;

<JobPositionPostings>
  <JobPositionPosting>
    <JobAction>SomeNewValue</JobAction>
    <JobType>NewType</JobType>
    <SomeNewElement>test</SomeNewElement>
    <JobPositionPostingID>27</JobPositionPostingID>
    <JobDisplayOptions>
      <MicrositeName>Client Microsite Name</MicrositeName>
      <TemplateName>Client Template Name</TemplateName>
    </JobDisplayOptions>
    <!-- More nodes -->
  </JobPositionPosting>
  <JobFeedResponseEmail>Tech person's E-mail for receiving Feed Status</JobFeedResponseEmail>
</JobPositionPostings>
```